# How to design a .net windows form application that never quit when user log out of Remote Desktop connection

Tags: .net, winforms, remote-desktop, quit

I am quite new to windows form app development. I have an app installed on a remote IIS server, this app is an agent that check and process job queue every 10 minutes.

But if I click "Start" - "Log off" on the server to disconnect my Remote Desktop connection session. The application quits as well.

Is there anyway to setup the windows form app to keep unless until a server restart or shutdown?

I know windows service applciation can do that but in this business case, windows service app will not be an alternative solution.

Comment: A GUI app closes when you log out. Therefore, a GUI app is the *wrong solution* for you.

Comment: @Andrew Barber thank you Andrew, looks like windows service is the only solution then?

Comment: It's by far the *best* solution. Then create a WinForms app to manage the service.

Comment: cheers! I will give it a go and setup win service to startup automatically with windows.

Comment: Strange, why do you log-off to terminate the connection?  Just quit the client, your app will keep running.

Comment: Remote deskstop sessions are shared between a couple of developers. team leader requires everyone to logoff properly to avoid locked or corrupted sessions. so unfortunately we can't just click the close button on the right top corner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows forms app just won't do what you're asking for.  Forms apps run in the logged-on user context and stop executing when you log off.  If you can't use a Windows service, you'll have to find another way.